# Consulta SQL totales agrupada y ordenada por mes y año

Tags: sql, sql-server

He visto varios hilos similares, pero no pude entender del todo. Básicamente, necesito mostrar la cantidad de registros de una tabla agrupados por mes y año , en orden ASC por mes y año.
Algo parecido a :

```
1525 | Enero 2017
1210 | Febrero 2017
1105 | Marzo 2017
```

En mi tabla tengo un campo identity "ID" que usé para sumar : sum (ID), y un campo datetime "FEC_CONS" , he probado modificaciones pero no me queda como quisiera. Copio lo que armé :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CANTIDAD, 
MONTH(FEC_CONS) as Mes, YEAR(FEC_CONS) as Año 
FROM LISTADO
GROUP BY MONTH(FEC_CONS),YEAR(FEC_CONS)
ORDER BY YEAR(FEC_CONS)
```

Comment: yo no veo nada malo en ese query.. cuales son los datos de entrada y que produce eso que no funciona como esperas?

Comment: Y cual es el problema pq dices q no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Disulpen demora en responder,tuve problemas con mi equipo. La sentencia era correcta , había un problema de formato con los datos. Gracias !!